# What's the earliest time to run MachineFunctionPass?

Tags: llvm

As `MachineFunctionPass::runOnMachineFunction` runs on `MachineFunction` in llvm, what's does `MachineFunction` mean here? Is the earliest time to run such pass after the code generation of the function in IR format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MachineFunction is after instruction selection and "scheduling", i.e after SelectionDAG.

See: http://llvm.org/docs/CodeGenerator.html#high-level-design-of-the-code-generator ; MachineInstrs are created step 2 and MachinFunctionPass can start to run step 3.

Comment: But `XXXDAGToDAGISel` is also a `MachineFunctionPass`, at which time the instruction selected has not been started.

Comment: DAGToDAGISel is the instruction selection, it is exactly the pass that populate the MachineFunction with MachineInstrs, see http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~yongli/notes/llvm5/LLVM5.html for a detailed walkthrough.